# jQuery Delegation with Facebox

Tags: jquery

**hi, i am not sharing code. the problem is in this code please take a look. (problem: I want to open facebox every time when post even come from ajax facebox is not working properly. I want to ask how to use jQuery delegation event with this event? )**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="facebox/facebox.css" type="text/css" />    
</head>
<body>

<ul id="items">
    <li> <a href='#'> Clone Object </a> </li>
    <li> <a href='#test' rel='facebox'> Click to open facebox </a> </li>
</ul>

<div id="test" style="display:none;">this is my test div</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="facebox/facebox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();

    $("#items li").delegate('a', 'click', function(){
        $(this).parent().append('<li><a href="#test" rel="facebox"> New Element ( problem: it should open facebox) </a></li>');
        return false;
    });

</script> 

</bdoy>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question? This is not a code sharing site.

Comment: hi, i am not sharing code. the problem is in this code please take a look. (problem: I want to open facebox every time when post even come from ajax facebox is not working properly. I want to ask how to use jQuery delegation event with this event? )

Comment: @Felix - the question is in the code, though yes it should be clearer outside, zarpio updated though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things, first change to using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), by switching this:

```
jQuery('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
```

For this:

```
jQuery('a[rel*=facebox]').live('click', function(e) {
  $.facebox({ div: this.hash });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) version:

```
$('#items').delegate('a[rel*=facebox]', 'click', function(e) {
  $.facebox({ div: this.hash });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

Then your [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) call is appending an `<li>` to an `<li>`, instead you should replace:

```
$(this).parent()
```

With [`.cloest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) so it goes up to the `<ul>` and appends it as a child *there*, like this:

```
$(this).closest("ul")
```

[You can test out the updated version with the above changes (without images) here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/UuccA/).